# Reference for author of "The earth has music for those who listen"

Tags: quote-source

> The earth has music for those who listen.

I just came to know about this quote but I found out that the author is not known. Some say it's by William Shakespeare, others say George Santayana and others say something different.

I want to use this quote in my video but I can't find author's name so can't use it as I should  mention the author's name too. Is there any reference which tells who actually said these words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reginald Vincent Holmes

... possibly. He did say it, though.

It's definitely [*not* Shakespeare](https://checkyourfact.com/2019/09/03/fact-check-shakespeare-earth-music-those-listen/), or if it is him, then it's not anywhere that multiple experts can find. It's also [probably not Santayana](http://www.shakespearegeek.com/2013/07/.html/the-earth-has-music-for-those-who-listen); people can't find a reference for that either. Well, except [this person](https://thatsnotshakespeare.tumblr.com/post/24776584144/also-the-full-verse-by-george-santayana-is), who quotes a poem they attribute to Santayana. Only problem is, that poem *isn't* by Santayana. The verse in question is:

> **The earth has its music for those who will listen**,
> Its bright variations forever abound;
> With all the wonders that God has bequeathed us,
> There is nothing that thrills like the magic of sound.

Which is probably from Holmes. There is, for example, [this 2001 newsletter](http://www.wheelinghistoricalsociety.com/news/2001-01%20Newsletter.pdf) crediting him, and multiple sources point back to **the poem ["The Magic of Sound"](http://stephanebarthelemy.com/hello-world) from his book [*Fireside Fancies*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30816242-fireside-fancies)**. Not having said book or anything but The Internets to go on, I can't be completely sure of this. But it seems more likely than Shakespeare or Santayana, at least.

Comment: [Here's a 1970 high school yearbook](https://archive.org/details/ERIC_ED059926/page/n159/mode/2up) attributing the verse to "Reginal Holmes" [sic].